# Create a new dataframe from specific columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to use columns to create new rows in a new dataframe.

```py
>>> df_1
  mix_id      ngs    phr   d      mp1      mp2    mp1_wt    mp2_wt    mp1_phr    mp2_phr
2    M01  SBR2353  100.0 NaN  MES/HPD  SBR2353  0.253731  0.746269  25.373134  74.626866
3    M02  SBR2054   80.0 NaN     TDAE  SBR2054  0.264706  0.735294  21.176471  58.823529
```

I would like to have a dataframe like this.

```py
>>> df_2
  mix_id      ngs        phr    d
1    M01  MES/HPD  25.373134  NaN
2    M01  SBR2353  74.626866  NaN
3    M02     TDAE  21.176471  NaN
4    M02  SBR2054  58.823529  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

you can use pd.wide_to_long, it does however needs the repeating columns to have numbers as suffix. So, the first part of solution, just renames the columns to bring the number as suffix

```
df.columns=[col for col in df.columns[:6]] + [re.sub(r'\d','',col) +  str(re.search(r'(\d)',col).group(0)) for col in df.columns[6:] ]
# this makes mp1_wt as mp_wt1, to support pd.wide_to_long

df2=pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['mp','mp_wt','mp_phr'], i=['mix_id','ngs','d'], j='val').reset_index().drop(columns='val')
df2.drop(columns=['ngs','phr','mp_wt'], inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'mp':'ngs','mp_phr':'phr'}, inplace=True)
df2
```

```
    mix_id    d     ngs         phr
0   M01     NaN     MES/HPD     25.373134
1   M01     NaN     SBR2353     74.626866
2   M02     NaN     TDAE        21.176471
3   M02     NaN     SBR2054     58.823529
```

Comment: It works indeed but there is a possibility the column indexes could change in the future.

Comment: it work with increasing column indexes as well. The rule to rename the column is general, which essentially shifting the number to the end